# Initiating a Skype Call with Button onClick

Tags: java, android, android-intent, skype

I want to initiate a Skype call on button click. I looked up several solutions available but most of I am guessing are outdated and are not working. Could someone please help me with this? I am very new to Android Programming. I have included by code below. Any help will be appreciated.

---

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

public void CallVideo(Context myContext, String mySkypeUri){

```
   Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse(mySkypeUri);
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, skypeUri);

   myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
   myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

   myContext.startActivity(myIntent);

   return;
```

}
}

---

activity_main.xml

```
  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Video Call"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:onClick="CallVideo"/>
```

Comment: Whats the uri you pass ? your method is correct for initiating skype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is correct.

For Skype voice call :

```
 CallVideo(getApplicationContext(), "skype:" + skypeUserName + "?call");
```

For Skype video call :

```
CallVideo(getApplicationContext(), "skype:" + skypeUserName + "?call&video=true");
```

For Skype chat :

```
 CallVideo(getApplicationContext(), "skype:" + skypeUserName + "?chat");
```

For Skype phone call :

```
 CallVideo(getApplicationContext(), "tel:" + phoneNumber);
```

using Intent.ACTION_VIEW will open the skype call page but call will not be initiated.

if Skype phone call need to be initiated the intent action needs to be Intent.ACTION_CALL and add permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

And yeah dont forget to check if Skype is installed or not before calling intents.